# Texture Imported From Unity Not Showing Up OpenGL

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, opengl, textures

I am trying to get the camera render texture from unity and display it on my opengl window triangle. I can get a regular texture to show up but the unity one results in a black screen.

Here is the function that runs once:

```
extern "C" void UNITY_INTERFACE_EXPORT UNITY_INTERFACE_API createSimpleWindow()
{

    if (std::this_thread::get_id() == MAIN_THREAD_ID)
    {


        newContext = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "window", NULL, oldContext);
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(newContext);
        //drawing triangle
        // start GLEW extension handler
        glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
        glewInit();
        // tell GL to only draw onto a pixel if the shape is closer to the viewer
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // enable depth-testing
        glDepthFunc(GL_LESS); // depth-testing interprets a smaller value as "closer"
//triangle pts
        float points[] = {
            0.0f,  0.5f,  0.0f,     0.5f, 1.0f,
            0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,     1.0f, 0.0f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f
        };
        GLuint vbo = 0;
        glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 15 * sizeof(float), points, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

         vao = 0;
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
        glBindVertexArray(vao);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

        GLuint vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(vs, 1, &vertex_shader, NULL);
        glCompileShader(vs);
        GLuint fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(fs, 1, &fragment_shader, NULL);
        glCompileShader(fs);

        shader_programme = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(shader_programme, fs);
        glAttachShader(shader_programme, vs);
        glLinkProgram(shader_programme);
         glUseProgram(shader_programme);
        ////////////////////////////
        //unity texture
        void* textureDataPtr = s_CurrentAPI->BeginModifyTexture(g_TextureHandle, g_TextureWidth, g_TextureHeight, &textureRowPitch);

        if (textureDataPtr) {
            writeToLog("data contained from unity!!!!!!");
        }

        //regular texture
        int width, height, nrComponents;
        unsigned char *data = stbi_load("/Users/roma/Desktop/Escape Tech/BitBucketRepos/blankpluginGLFW/BlankPlugin/PluginSource/source/container2.png", &width, &height, &nrComponents, 4);

       //set up texture
        glGenTextures(1, &texture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

        //glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, g_TextureWidth, g_TextureHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureDataPtr);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureDataPtr);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader_programme, "texture1"), 0);


        //s_CurrentAPI->EndModifyTexture(g_TextureHandle, g_TextureWidth, g_TextureHeight, textureRowPitch, textureDataPtr);

        //////////////////////////////////
        glfwSetKeyCallback(newContext, key_callback);
    }
    else
    {
        writeToLog("not main thread");
    }
}
```

```
void* RenderAPI_OpenGLCoreES::BeginModifyTexture(void* textureHandle, int textureWidth, int textureHeight, int* outRowPitch)
{
    const int rowPitch = textureWidth * 4;
    // Just allocate a system memory buffer here for simplicity
    unsigned char* data = new unsigned char[rowPitch * textureHeight];
    *outRowPitch = rowPitch;
    return data;
}
```

When I do a "if (textureDataPtr)" write to log it writes correctly so I know there is data it is just not showing up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `glTexImage2D(...g_TextureWidth, g_TextureHeight...)` rather than `glTexImage2D(...width, height...)`?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yes, that is correct. I changed it but the problem still persists.